# java errorlistener use on a transformer instance(jaxp)

Tags: java, transform, jaxp, transformer-model

The signature for method transform of `Transformer` is `void  transform(Source xmlSource,Result outputTarget)throws TransformerException` i.e. specifies that it
throws a checked exception of type TransformerException.
I can not understand how `ErrorListener` fits in.
If an `ErrorListener` is set to `Transform` object does this mean that the exception will not be thrown?
If it is thrown anyway how is an ErrorListener useful?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ErrorListener` is not set, the error/warning message will go to `System.err`, so it is useful to redirect error messages. It is up to application to decide should it continue transformation, if an error/warning occured. If the appropriate method in `ErrorListener` throws an exception, the transformation will exit with `TransformerException`. On `fatalError` transformation will be stopped, even if `ErrorListener::fatalError` doesn't throw an exception.

**Update** Summary

1. `TransformerException` is thrown, when a fatal error occurs, and this doesn't depend on `ErrorListener` or whether it is set or not.
2. `TransformerException` is thrown, when a recoverable error or a warning occurs, the `ErrorListener` is set, and the corresponding method (`error` or `warning`) has thrown an exception. So the application can decide what to do on rec. errors and warnings.

Comment: You mean that the TransformerException is thrown anyway, but in the catch clause you can not log the error/warning msg?Isn't it included in the TransformerException? I am not sure I got your answer. Is the Transformer exception thrown regardless of the errorlistener being set?

Comment: So if no errorlistener is set, TransformerException is thrown for fatal errors only? And what happens if recoverable error or a warning occurs and no errorlistener is set?

Comment: @user384706 a) yes, if `ErrorListener` doesn't throw exception on `error` and `warning`; b) it writes the reports to `System.err`.